# How do I load a geoJson file to display into matplotlib on Python to display?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, geojson, qgis

I basically want to load a geojson file, like you would in QGIS or Leaflet, but in something like matplotlib. I want to do it this way so I can load a ton (6000 geojson files to be exact), change some of the styling, and then export them as images.

I've followed other links such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081188/how-to-plot-geo-data-using-matplotlib-python)...but am getting KeyErrors when I try to set the 'bounds' in this method.

```
def setPlotExtent(ax, data):
    # get feature extents (a property of the cloudmade geojson)
    # note this was previously bbox
    minx = data['bounds'][0][0]
    maxx = data['bounds'][1][0]
    miny = data['bounds'][0][1]
    maxy = data['bounds'][1][1]

    # set the graph axes to the feature extents
    ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
    ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)
```

I've tried doing this in QGIS but not much success, I've considered trying to download ArcGIS trial and do it but doing it with matplot lib would be the easiest.

In pseudocode, all I want to do is something like...

```
for geoJsonFile in geoJsonDir
    loadIntoMatPlotLib(geoJsonFile)
    changeSomeFeatures()
    exportAsPNG()
```

My full code is here...(which is pretty much just what was in that other stack question)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import simplejson

def configurePlot():
    # set up the mapplotlib
    fig = pyplot.figure(1, figsize=(10, 4), dpi=180)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
    return fig, ax


def setPlotExtent(ax, data):
    # get feature extents (a property of the cloudmade geojson)
    # note this was previously bbox
    minx = data['bounds'][0][0]
    maxx = data['bounds'][1][0]
    miny = data['bounds'][0][1]
    maxy = data['bounds'][1][1]

    # set the graph axes to the feature extents
    ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
    ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)


def plotFeature(coordinates, myplot):
    poly = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": coordinates}
    patch = PolygonPatch(poly, fc='#6699cc', ec='#6699cc', alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
    # plot it on the graph
    myplot.add_patch(patch)


# turn the geojson into a python object
with open(r"Geo_AOI_1_RIO_img163.geojson") as f:
    pydata = simplejson.load(f)
print(pydata)

fig, myplot = configurePlot()
setPlotExtent(myplot, pydata)

plotFeature(pydata['coordinates'], myplot)

# save the plot as an image
pyplot.show()
fig.savefig('myplot.png')
```

Ultimately, this is the image I am trying to generate from the GeoJSON file. I did it manually in QGIS.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer to this question, but I ended up just being able to do this in QGIS writing a script in PyQGIS. It is very slow on there and gets the job done, but if anyone knows a way not using QGIS please answer!